# Flutter: How to Pass Barcode Scan value into TextFormField

Tags: flutter, barcode

I want to pass the Barcode scan value into the Serial Number that in the TextFromField.
Is there any way to do it?
Please help me to fix it out .

```
class Scan extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ScanState createState() => _ScanState();
}

class _ScanState extends State<Scan> {
  String _data = "";

  _scan() async {
    await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
            '#000000', 'Cancel', true, ScanMode.BARCODE)
        .then((value) => setState(() => _data = value));
  }

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Maintenance Log'),
      ),
      body: Card(
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(_data),
                    Container(
                      width: 200.0,
                      child: TextFormField(
                        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Serial Number'),
                        validator: (val) {
                          if (val.length == 0) {
                            return "S/N is Required";
                          } else {
                            return null;
                          }
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                    Spacer(),
                    RaisedButton(
                      child: Text('Scan Barcode'),
                      onPressed: () => _scan(),
                    ),
                    Spacer(flex: 2),
                  ],
                ),
```

Thank you for your help. :D
P.S. I am a student who is starting to write apps as a project. This is my first app.

Answer (score 1):

Add a TextFormFieldController,
add the controller to the textformfield.
then booom!!

```
_scan() async {
    await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode(
            '#000000', 'Cancel', true, ScanMode.BARCODE)
        .then((value) => setState(() => textFormFieldController.text = value));
  }
```

this will do it :)